# WSO2 Developer Studio. Names of customsequences are not visible in WSO2 API Manger perspective

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2-integration-studio

When I connect to WSO API Manager server in API Manager perspective of WSO2 Developer Studio and switch the names of existing customsequences are not visible in a repository tree:

[image]

Is it problem of font colour or something other?

I'm working with  Windows10 and WSO2 Developers Studio 3.8.

```
!SESSION 2016-08-09 11:20:18.197 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.8.0_92
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

!ENTRY org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE Keybinding conflicts occurred.  They may interfere with normal accelerator operation.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+V:
Binding(CTRL+V,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.paste,Paste,
        Paste from the clipboard,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@38568876,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+V,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.paste,Paste Registry Element,
        Paste Registry Element Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@59456e1,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for DEL:
Binding(DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.delete,Delete,
        Delete the selection,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@765e5a55,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(DEL,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.delete,Delete Registry Element,
        Delete Registry Element Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7a8dbbf1,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+INSERT:
Binding(CTRL+INSERT,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy,Copy,
        Copy the selection to the clipboard,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1ee5792a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+INSERT,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.addresource,Add Registry Resource,
        Add Registry Resource Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@71ad1d0b,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for F5:
Binding(F5,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.file.refresh,Refresh,
        Refresh the selected items,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@5e528476,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(F5,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.refresh,Refresh Registry Tree,
        Refresh Registry Tree Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@7a087132,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for F2:
Binding(F2,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.rename,Rename,
        Rename the selected item,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.file,File,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@11d557a5,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.window,,,system)
Binding(F2,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.rename,Rename Registry Element,
        Rename Registry Element Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@5d8c03cc,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.jface 2 0 2016-08-09 11:20:23.044
!MESSAGE A conflict occurred for CTRL+C:
Binding(CTRL+C,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.eclipse.ui.edit.copy,Copy,
        Copy the selection to the clipboard,
        Category(org.eclipse.ui.category.edit,Edit,null,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@1ee5792a,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.eclipse.ui.contexts.dialogAndWindow,,,system)
Binding(CTRL+C,
    ParameterizedCommand(Command(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.commands.copy,Copy Registry Element,
        Copy Registry Element Command,
        Category(org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.category,WSO2 Registry Category,WSO2 Registry Browser Command Category,true),
        org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchHandlerServiceHandler@4a4979bf,
        ,,true),null),
    org.eclipse.ui.defaultAcceleratorConfiguration,
    org.wso2.developerstudio.registry.browser.keybindings.context,,,system)
```

Comment: Hi Tadeus are you able to open and view a custom sequence even though the name is not generated? Also can you check for any errors that is logged in dev studio and edit your question with the stacktrace. You can find the log file located in your dev studio workspace/.metadata folder.

Comment: I have the same problem in a clustered api manager enviroment but the problem didn't appear in a single node enviroment, and I see this kind of behaviour under windows and osx

Comment: Hi Jason. Yes, I.m able to open, view and edit custom sequence even though the name isn't visible in tree.

Comment: I have added to my question all .log from Developer Studio start to opening of a custom sequence